# How make JavaScript work by replacing with bygetElementById with getElementsByClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am referring to one of the SOF answers for sorting the alphabets in second column using javascript, here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/mLYch/159/ .

In JS side it has getElementById and calling HTML tag with id

```
 <table id="caltbl">

 var tbl = document.getElementById("caltbl").tBodies[0];
```

I tried the same with the class and it doesn't work.

```
 <table class="caltbl">

 var tbl = document.getElementsByClass('caltbl').tBodies[0];
```

Can someone please assist on how to use make the script run without ID ?

Comment: `getElementsByClass` always returns a collection. So `var tbl = document.getElementsByClass('caltbl')[0].tBodies[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `.querySelector` instead if you only want the first one.

```
var tbl = document.querySelector('.caltbl > tbody');
```

---

Or if you want multiple, use a loop with `.querySelectorAll`.

```
var tbls = document.querySelectorAll('.caltbl > tbody:first-of-type');
for (var i = 0; i < tbls.length; i++) {
  var tbl = tbls[i];
  // ...
}
```

Or you can use the loop with `.getElementsByClassName` if you prefer.

Comment: var tbl = document.querySelector('.caltbl > tbody'); worked.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClass` returns an array (since there can me more than one element with that class), so you'd have to change your code to

```
var tbl = document.getElementsByClass('caltbl')[0].tBodies[0];
```